# $request->isXmlHttpRequest() returns false

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, symfony

I am trying to send json data to my Symfony2 controller, using $.ajax method of jquery (1.12.4).

My javascript:

```
         var category_type = 2;
         var json_data = JSON.stringify(category_type);

         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: Routing.generate('homepage'),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: "json",
            data: json_data,
            beforeSend: function (xhr){
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
            },
            success: function (result, status, xhr) {
               console.log(result);
               console.log(status);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
               console.log(error);
               console.log(status);
            }
        });
```

My controller:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/", name="homepage", options={"expose"=true})
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request) {

    if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
        $content = $this->get("request")->getContent();
        $cat = json_decode($content, true);
        var_dump($content);
        exit;
    }
    else {
        echo 'Sorry!';
        exit;
    }
```

However I get the message Sorry! everytime. Now I am not sure if I used `xhr: setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With","XMLHttpRequest"),` correctly. But without it I get the same result.

I've also tried removing the `if/else` condition and tried `$content = $this->get("request")->getContent();`. But when I do `var_dump($content);`, I get an empty string ie. `string '' (length=0)`

**Question:**

1. Why does `$request->isXmlHttpRequest()` return `false`?
2. How do I set the request header?
3. Is this the correct way to send json data to the server(`$.ajax`)?
4. Is this the correct way to receive data in the controller(`$this->get("request")->getContent();`)?

Comment: Have you tried without the line `xhr: setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With","XMLHttpRequest")` i usually don't specify nothing client-side....

Comment: @Matteo Yes I have. But I get the same result.

Comment: @Matteo check out the second answer in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658789/symfony-request-isxmlhttprequest-issue

Comment: can your webServer/proxy/cacheManager filter for some http header?

Comment: @Matteo I am not sure how to check that.

Comment: ok, probably not...

Comment: @Matteo I've updated the code, instead of xhr option, i now use `beforeSend: function (xhr){
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
                },`  Same result though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it in your ajax call:

```
data: { json_data }
```

instead of :

```
data: json_data
```

And if you want to see POST data from request you have to do this :

```
dump($request->request);
```

=> I advise you to use the `dump` function (SF 2.6 => see [doc](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-vardumper-component) to use it)

**EDIT**

Try to do this simple call and if it works you just have to reproduce this with your own data:

```
var data = {"name":"John Doe"}
$.ajax({
    dataType : "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data : JSON.stringify(data),
    success : function(result) {
        alert(result.success); // result is an object which is created from the returned JSON
    },
});
```

Comment: I tried `data: { json_data }` but the success callback `success: function (result, status, xhr) {alert(result);}` gives null value

Comment: If you `console.log` your "json_data" before ajax call it is not empty ? And in your controller just do a `dump($request->request);exit;`

Comment: tried this as well. The result is `DefaultController.php on line 34:
ParameterBag {#9 ▼
  #parameters: []
}`

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)